# How to give UIdatepicker non-gregorian calendar w/ gregorian value

Tags: nsdateformatter, uidatepicker, gregorian-calendar

Using this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

having defaults of '2014' on my datepicker,
Using Thai calendar gives me headache for displaying a year of 2557 (which is of course in Thai locale) to its year picker on the UIdatepicker. yes that is correct - but I want to get it's value in gregorian calendar format so I could save it on the database without any worries. can I do that on my  NSDateFormatter? (also including hours, minutes, and days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setCalendar:gregorianCalendar];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```